# Why brew installion failed?

Tags: java, macos, installation, homebrew

I installed java11 using Home Brew but that failed. So some help needed to get Java works!

Thanks for advance!

```
admin@mac ~ % brew install java11
Warning: openjdk@11 11.0.12 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 11.0.12, run:  
brew reinstall openjdk@11
```

Then brew reinstall java11

```
 admin@mac  ~ % brew reinstall java11
    ==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/openjdk/11/manifests/11.0.12
    Already downloaded: /Users/admin/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/45acc78f00cc0cf39a75f562f544fd9b61dc415df386dd1cb9b886c1f553252d--openjdk@11-11.0.12.bottle_manifest.json
    ==> Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/openjdk/11/blobs/sha256:dbf0b347060474c1aa0fbe3e58e33f4d81337e6f49209761da130ee776d66355
    Already downloaded: /Users/admin/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/f08afa8f068cb282e649564e38b9fbe4aafc8e7f0d7b969fa17651c6df2f14e5--openjdk@11--11.0.12.arm64_big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
    ==> Reinstalling openjdk@11
    ==> Pouring openjdk@11--11.0.12.arm64_big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
    ==> Caveats
    For the system Java wrappers to find this JDK, symlink it with
      sudo ln -sfn /opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@11/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.jdk
    
    openjdk@11 is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /opt/homebrew,
    because this is an alternate version of another formula.
    
    If you need to have openjdk@11 first in your PATH, run:
      echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@11/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
    
    For compilers to find openjdk@11 you may need to set:
      export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@11/include"
    
    ==> Summary
      /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk@11/11.0.12: 670 files, 273.0MB
    ==> Running `brew cleanup openjdk@11`...
    Disable this behaviour by setting HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP.
    Hide these hints with HOMEBREW_NO_ENV_HINTS (see `man brew`).
```

After reinstall:

```
   admin@mac ~ % echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@11/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

And test java -version

```
admin@mac ~ % java -version
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.
```

Also:

```
admin@mac ~ %  sudo ln -sfn /opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk@11/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.jdk
Password:
ln: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.jdk: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You’ll need to reload your shell after updating `.zshrc`

Comment: Didn’t work....

Answer (score 1):

> ln: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.jdk: No such file or directory

The purpose of the linking command is to create the file `openjdk-11.jdk` in the stated directory. The error suggests that this directory doesn't actually exist.

Try creating the directory `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/` and rerunning the linking command.